# What are the semantics of numpy advanced indexing in-place increments when the indices overlap?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to increment a numpy array using advanced indexing, e.g.

```
import numpy
x = numpy.array([0,0])
indices = numpy.array([1,1])
x[indices] += [1,2]
print x #prints [0 2]
```

I would have expected, that the result is [0 3], since both 1 and 2 should be added to the second zero of x, but apparently numpy only adds the last element which matches to a particular index. 
Is this the general behaviour and I can rely on that, or is this undefined behaviour and could change with a different version of numpy?

Additionally, is there an (easy) way to get numpy to add all elements which match the index and not just the last one?

Comment: You can use `np.add.at` there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From numpy [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> For advanced assignments, there is in general no guarantee for the iteration order. This means that if an element is set more than once, it is not possible to predict the final result.

You can use np.add.at to get the desired behaviour:

> Help on built-in function at in numpy.add:
>
> numpy.add.at = at(...) method of numpy.ufunc instance
>       at(a, indices, b=None)
>
> ```
> Performs unbuffered in place operation on operand 'a' for elements
> specified by 'indices'. For addition ufunc, this method is equivalent to
> `a[indices] += b`, except that results are accumulated for elements that
> are indexed more than once. For example, `a[[0,0]] += 1` will only
> increment the first element once because of buffering, whereas
> `add.at(a, [0,0], 1)` will increment the first element twice.
>
> .. versionadded:: 1.8.0
> ```

< snip >

Example:

```
>>> b = np.ones(2, int)
>>> a = np.zeros(2, int)
>>> c = np.arange(2,4)
>>> np.add.at(a, b, c)
>>> a
array([0, 5])
```

Comment: I wasn't even sure how to search for that after the non-surprising observation of discarded operations. Glad i found this as the solution is somewhat hidden in the docs. Thanks!